# installed selenium but doesn't work in jupytor notebook

Tags: selenium-webdriver

i've installed selenium module via cmd 'pip install selenium' and completed install

this is my screen. i don't know why it doesn't work out properly

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w3ni.png)

installed selenium via cmd

moved 'chromedriver.exe' file to C:\windows